# Check for value in headers/body in kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm totally new to KOTLIN, I have a use case where I have to check if a value is passed in headers.

```
    @PostMapping("/users")
    fun createUser(@RequestBody userRegistry: UserRegistryDTO?) {
        logger.info("********************************"+userRegistry)
        }
```

Using the above code, I'm able to retrieve the value from a payload. How to retrieve the value from headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of header by using parameter with `@RequestHeader` annotation

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("/users")
    fun createUser(
        @RequestBody userRegistry: UserRegistryDTO?,
        @RequestHeader("my-header") myHeader: String?
    ) : ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> {
        if (myHeader == null) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Anjana did this answer help?